# Binomial probability given the mean

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, binomial-distribution

> You examine each tree in a 25 ft by 25 ft section of forest and record whether or not that tree is infected. Based on historical data, the average number of trees that would be expected to be infected in a section of this size is $3$.
>
> What is the probability that you would find at least $2$ infected trees in a section of this size?
>
> (a) $0.7760$
>
> (b) $0.8009$
>
> (c) $0.2240$
>
> (d) $0.5768$

My impression was that there is insufficient information. If the number of trees in the plot were given, I would compute $$\sum_{k=2}^N \binom Nk \bigg(\frac{3}N\bigg)^k \bigg(1-\frac{3}N\bigg)^{n-k}$$ but I don't have the denominator $N$. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: This does depend on the number of trees in the plot.

Comment: Is there a closed form for the summation above? If so, could I solve for each of the answer choices and check if the $N$ satisfying the equation is plausible?

Comment: Well, you can use $1 - \mathbb P(X=0) - \mathbb P(X=1)$ which seems to be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT...This requires the use of the **Poisson** distribution with parameter $\lambda=3$, find $p(X\geq2)$

Comment: $\sum_{x=2}^\infty \frac{3^x}{e^3 x!} = 1 - 4/e^3 \approx 0.8009$

Comment: Yes indeed!....

Comment: Though that assumes a potentially unlimited number of trees could fit in a small plot

Comment: @Henry yes, this is one of various assumptions which need to be made in order to use the Poisson distribution, and such an assumption is always made whenever the Poisson distribution is used. Luckily for large values of $X$ the probabilities become vanishingly small, which makes such assumptions reasonable.

Comment: @DavidQuinn So the Poisson assumptions assume an infinite $N$? How do we reconcile that with the binomial definition if we take the limit as $N \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @TiwaAina the Binomial Distribution does not apply in this case. For it to apply you would have to have a fixed $N$ and fixed $p$. The answer we get using Poisson is only an approximation. The distribution is not exactly Poisson since there is a limit to the number of diseased tress you could fit into a square as described.